# CRUD operations on list of items instead of a single one in ChicagoBoss

Tags: erlang, chicagoboss

I'm a newbie to ChicagoBoss and Erlang in general, so please bear with me.

I have a model of Options which represent a number of site configurations (think of the [available options in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference), since it's modeled after it), to which I have to perform CRUD operations on.

The model looks like this:

```
-module(options,
    [
        Id, 
        KeyName::string(),
        Value::string(),
        IsActive::string()
    ]
).
-compile(export_all).
```

Each option is prefixed by its category, so general options names look like "general_option_" followed by its specific name.

The views for Options are mostly a list of inputs with each input linked to a specific option, as you might expect.

Since the number and name of options is not known beforehand (except in the view), I would like to know what approaches there are for dealing with this case, as every example I've seen so far deals with a single item, and not a list of them. Please share any advice or constructive criticism you have, as it will be very welcome.